# ZipEntry() and converting persian filenames

Tags: vb.net, persian, sharpziplib

In my vb.net project I'm trying to add a file with a Persian name to a zip file and I do this with the code bellow:

```
Dim myentry As New ZipEntry(dr.Item("MyFile").ToString())
zipOut.PutNextEntry(myentry)
```

however when I open the zip file I see the file name is changed to a gibberish

Is there a way to fix this problem?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `IsUnicodeText` to `true`:

```
'VB.NET
Dim newEntry = New ZipEntry(entryName) With { _
        Key .DateTime = DateTime.Now, _
        Key .Size = size, _
        Key .IsUnicodeText = True _
    }

//C#
var newEntry = new ZipEntry(entryName)
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                Size = size,
                IsUnicodeText = true
            };
```

Comment: thanks for answering...In VB.net I'm not allowed to do so....at least not like this